# Can I fade a background image into the background color?

Tags: css

I want a website to have a background color, and a background image that scales with the width, and keeps the aspect ratio. So far pretty easy:

```
body {
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-color:#ff9999;
    background-image:url(https://i.redd.it/x7hdjnmupu901.jpg); // random image from google search
    background-position:top center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% auto;
}
```

Now, is it possible with CSS to have the background image to the bottom side 'fade into' the background color? As in, have the bottom 50 pixels of the background image slowly lose alpha value, so it smoothly goes into the background color?

Here is a JSFiddle, if someone wants to see this / play around with it: http://jsfiddle.net/wkz1t2b3/5/

Comment: if you want to fading the color with pixel, then use background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,153,153,0) 0%,rgba(255,153,153,0) 50px,rgba(255,153,153,1) 100%), url(https://i.redd.it/x7hdjnmupu901.jpg);

Comment: @AmranurRahman See my answer below.

Comment: o its ok, I don't see this.

Comment: @AmranurRahman Not a problem :) Just thought OP's response may be valuable to anyone else considering the `linear-gradient` method.

Comment: do you need it on the body, or it can be inside a div ?

Comment: I'd need it in the body here, since it's for the actual background image of the website

Answer (score 11):

You could use `linear-gradient` to apply a second background-image, which is a gradient of your background color from `0` opacity to `100%` opacity.

You can edit the `75%` in the below `linear-gradient` to change the point at which the fade begins, and the `100%` to adjust the point at which the background-color becomes fully visible.

```css
body {
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-color:#ff9999;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,153,153,0) 0%,rgba(255,153,153,0) 75%,rgba(255,153,153,1) 100%), url(https://i.redd.it/x7hdjnmupu901.jpg);
    background-position:top center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% auto;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it's not really working properly. Try to view your snippet as full page, and reduce the width of your browser, eventually you will have the image, a sharp transition to black background color and at the bottom it will fade into the actual background color.

Comment: @user2015253 Scratch that previous comment. Not sure of a way to do this, or if it's even possible without adding some more elements, but I'll have to sleep on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, if you want the fadding be attached to the background image in any screen size, you will need to add some extra elements, and be tricky with the CSS

But it still behaves as a background ...

Test screen resizings in : http://jsfiddle.net/wkz1t2b3/77/

```css
body{ 
  margin:0px;
  background-color:#ff9999;
  color:white;
}

#background{
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1
}

#background img{width:100%;}

/* the body fade becomes visible only when the image is bigger than the viewport */
body::after{
    background-image:  linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #ff9999);
    content:'';
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    bottom:0px;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;
}

#background::after{
    background-image:  linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #ff9999);
    content:'';
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    bottom:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <img src="https://i.redd.it/x7hdjnmupu901.jpg">
</div>


It behaves as a background
```

Comment: How good or safe is it to use CSS trickery like this? Is it sure to work across all browsers and is it future-proof? Would it in general be better to photoshop the background image to have this transition to transparent (or the background color) in the image itself?

Comment: is totally safe & future-proof. I used the term 'tricky' because i'm adding a fadding to the background container, and another fadding to the body. If you want to support also older browsers versions, simply add the corresponding prefixes to `linear-gradient`, for modern browsers should work as it is.